# Need to generate mechanical vibrations for experiment in ISS

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, materials

For a school scientific experiment to be flown onboard the ISS in a few months, I need to generate mechanical waves in a cylindrical capsule made of polycarbonate filled with oil (height about 9 cm, radius about 2 cm, wall thickness a few mm) and electrically heated on one side. Objective is to study heat conduction in oil in microgravity, with and without mechanical vibrations propagating in the oil. Frequency needs to be varied and in the range 3 kHz to, say, 100 kHz. Amplitude of vibrations should be high enough to, hopefully, generate standing waves in the oil. Thought of using a ceramic heater to heat the oil, and a piezo transducer to generate the vibrations but really don't know about possible issues with these ideas. Any advice highly welcome !! Thanks !

Comment: Welcome to the site. You haven't really asked a question. This isn't a discussion forum, so open ended questions don't work here. Which part of your project are you having problems with? We need a specific question to be able to give a specific answer.

Comment: Ok, sorry. Thanks for your remark. I'll do some preliminary testings first with whatever piezo buzzer and ceramic or coil heater I can find and come back with precise questions.

Comment: How much vibratory power will you require in your design, and what is the purpose of the vibrations?